# Finding a book series - monster fighting teen who could lift a car with telekinesis?

Tags: story-identification, books

I know this question title could apply to many series but I thought I'd try anyway.

I'm really trying to find a book series I read a while ago, but I'm worried it maybe impossible as I remember so few and vague details.

Fairly sure it was set in modern times (2000 ish). It was new enough that I don't think it was finished when I stopped reading it

It's about some teen boy. I believe it was written in first person. He has some powers, but using them tires him out. One example, I think, was that he could lift a car with telekinesis. Eventually I think he is supposed to use his powers to fight monsters.

The start of the story is about him being sent away to live with this woman (W1) in some old manor in small town. Can't remember, but it may be because his father died.The opening was a stormy night. A mysterious but friendly man (M1) offers to drive him further than the taxi is willing to take him, up to the manor. Turns out that W1 dislikes M1 but later this is revealed to be due to a former (Romantic ?) relationship. Eventually it's revealed that both M1 and W1 know something about the supernatural goings-on (more than the main character at least).

The main character also develops friendship / relationship with W1's daughter G1. He also meets and hangs out with her friends.

I remember a chapter where the main character fought a gargoyle like creature in the manor.

I think in a later book he is transported back in time, and meets counter parts to M1, W1 and G1

I have a gut feeling that the name of series might have the boys name in it, or the name of the manor.

I know this is probably not a lot to go on...

Answer (score 2):

I came here all excited because I have the perfect fit for the title.
The description let me a little down because it matches less.

But after some hesitation, I will answer it anyway.

Turtle from the Wild Cards Series from G.R.R. Martin (the one).
http://wildcards.wikia.com/wiki/Turtle
I only read the origin story, in the Dreamsong Martin retrospective.

It was about a young man, with **telekinesis** power. When he says to his friend he wants to use his power as a superhero, his friend, more physically fit beat him, preventing to use his power.
So in order to keep his dream, this guy goes inside an armored **car he moves** using his telekinesis power.

I didn't read beyond the origin story, so i can't help about a real story.

Pro : 
Young guy moving a car with telekinesis
Not finished (GRR Martin books never are finished)

Against : 
What you describe also look like an origin story.
The time setting does not matches. (the story is set in the 60-70)